# Getting error "Unknown command: 'load_data'. Did you mean loaddata?" while running "python manage.py load_data"

Tags: python, django

While running `python manage.py load_data` I am getting an error `Unknown command: 'load_data'. Did you mean loaddata?`.

Below I have attached the folder structure where `load_data.py` is present.

[image: Folder structure]

I also tried running `python -m store_monitor.management.commands.load_data`  but still not working.

Comment: Try adding `__init__.py` files to your management and commands directories: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: load_data should be in the commands folder.  It looks like it's in the management folder.  [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) is a django word, so that's why it's saying, did you mean...